# Leaving a function empty on purpose?

Tags: php

I'm writing a little function library in PHP to simplify my routine coding tasks, and I've created a function called `ghead()`, which essentially, if not passed any arguments, displays my company logo, and if populated with arguments, replaces the logo with whatever arguments have been passed.

Though, PHP keeps calling the `'Warning: Missing argument 5 for gHead(), called in...'` error when I leave the function without arguments (which is what I'm trying to do!) - is it in any way possible to disable these without modifying PHP's settings via shell or direct access? I have cPanel access only. Here's some code:

```
//index.php
ghead("Dashboard", "'Open Sans'", "black","0","7px"); //works
ghead(); //errors! but works, just plastered in errors ?>


<?php //functions.php
function gHead($text,$font,$colour,$shadow,$push){
if($text==""){
$text = "company-name";}
if($font==""){
$font = "'TheoremRegular'"; }
if($colour==""){
$colour = "#00FF00"; }
if($push==""){
$push = 0; }
if($shadow==""){
$shadow = "6px"; }
echo "<style>#logo {background-color:#E8E8E8; border-bottom:2px solid #C8C8C8; z-index:2; opacity:0.7; width:100%; position:absolute; left:0; top:25px; height:70px; font-family:".$font."; font-size:46px;color:".$colour."; text-shadow: 0 0 ".$shadow." #000;  }.content{position:absolute;left:20px;margin-top:".$push."}#bod,#forgot_pass{background-color:#F8F8F8;position:absolute;left:0;top:95px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1;}</style>";
echo '<div id="logo"><div class="content">'.$text.'</div></div>'; }
```

Comment: please  , don't `echo` large portions of html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add default parameter values into the function declaration:

```
function gHead($text = "",$font = "",$colour = "",$shadow = "",$push = "")
```

Comment: right.. default parameters, you can read about them here www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-150 note that the last parameters should have default values if you decide to use them

Answer (score 0):

I think null will be better

```
function gHead($text = null,$font = null,$colour = null,$shadow = null,$push = null)
```